# `jax.errors.TracerArrayConversionError: The numpy.ndarray conversion method __array__() was called on traced array with shape float32[1,17].`

Tags: jax

I am trying to perform multiprocessing to parallelize my program (that uses JAX) using `pmap`. I am a newbie with JAX and realize that maybe pmap isn't the right approach. The documentation [here](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.pmap.html#jax.pmap), said that `pmap` can express SPMD programs (which is the case here) and therefore I decided to use it.

Here's my program. I am basically trying to run a reinforcement learning program (that uses JAX too) twice, using parallel execution -

```
'''
For installation please do -
pip install gym
pip install sbx
pip install mujoco
pip install shimmy
'''
import os
os.environ["XLA_FLAGS"] = '--xla_force_host_platform_device_count=8'

import jax
import gym
from sbx import SAC

def my_func():

    env = gym.make("Humanoid-v4")
    model = SAC("MlpPolicy", env,verbose=0)
    model.learn(total_timesteps=7e5, progress_bar=True)

from jax import pmap
import jax.numpy as jnp

out = pmap(lambda _: my_func())(jnp.arange(2))
```

I get the following error -

```
(tbd) thoma@thoma-Lenovo-Legion-5-15IMH05H:~/PycharmProjects/tbd$ python new.py
/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/vec_env/patch_gym.py:49: UserWarning: You provided an OpenAI Gym environment. We strongly recommend transitioning to Gymnasium environments. Stable-Baselines3 is automatically wrapping your environments in a compatibility layer, which could potentially cause issues.
  warnings.warn(
/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gym/utils/passive_env_checker.py:233: DeprecationWarning: `np.bool8` is a deprecated alias for `np.bool_`.  (Deprecated NumPy 1.24)
  if not isinstance(terminated, (bool, np.bool8)):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 17, in <module>
    out = pmap(lambda _: my_func())(jnp.arange(2))
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/traceback_util.py", line 166, in reraise_with_filtered_traceback
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/api.py", line 1779, in cache_miss
    execute = pxla.xla_pmap_impl_lazy(fun_, *tracers, **params)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/pxla.py", line 411, in xla_pmap_impl_lazy
    compiled_fun, fingerprint = parallel_callable(
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/linear_util.py", line 345, in memoized_fun
    ans = call(fun, *args)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/pxla.py", line 678, in parallel_callable
    pmap_computation = lower_parallel_callable(
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/profiler.py", line 314, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/pxla.py", line 825, in lower_parallel_callable
    jaxpr, consts, replicas, shards = stage_parallel_callable(pci, fun)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/pxla.py", line 748, in stage_parallel_callable
    jaxpr, out_sharded_avals, consts = pe.trace_to_jaxpr_final(
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/profiler.py", line 314, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/partial_eval.py", line 2233, in trace_to_jaxpr_final
    jaxpr, out_avals, consts = trace_to_subjaxpr_dynamic(
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/partial_eval.py", line 2177, in trace_to_subjaxpr_dynamic
    ans = fun.call_wrapped(*in_tracers_)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/linear_util.py", line 188, in call_wrapped
    ans = self.f(*args, **dict(self.params, **kwargs))
  File "new.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    out = pmap(lambda _: my_func())(jnp.arange(2))
  File "new.py", line 12, in my_func
    model.learn(total_timesteps=7e5, progress_bar=True)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sbx/sac/sac.py", line 173, in learn
    return super().learn(
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/off_policy_algorithm.py", line 328, in learn
    rollout = self.collect_rollouts(
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/off_policy_algorithm.py", line 557, in collect_rollouts
    actions, buffer_actions = self._sample_action(learning_starts, action_noise, env.num_envs)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/off_policy_algorithm.py", line 390, in _sample_action
    unscaled_action, _ = self.predict(self._last_obs, deterministic=False)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/base_class.py", line 553, in predict
    return self.policy.predict(observation, state, episode_start, deterministic)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sbx/common/policies.py", line 58, in predict
    actions = np.array(actions).reshape((-1, *self.action_space.shape))
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 605, in __array__
    raise TracerArrayConversionError(self)
jax._src.traceback_util.UnfilteredStackTrace: jax.errors.TracerArrayConversionError: The numpy.ndarray conversion method __array__() was called on traced array with shape float32[1,17].
The error occurred while tracing the function <lambda> at new.py:17 for pmap. This value became a tracer due to JAX operations on these lines:

  operation a:i32[] = convert_element_type[new_dtype=int32 weak_type=False] b
    from line new.py:11 (my_func)

  operation a:u32[] = convert_element_type[new_dtype=uint32 weak_type=False] b
    from line new.py:11 (my_func)

  operation a:f32[] = convert_element_type[new_dtype=float32 weak_type=False] b
    from line new.py:11 (my_func)

  operation a:f32[] = convert_element_type[new_dtype=float32 weak_type=False] b
    from line new.py:11 (my_func)

  operation a:f32[376,256] = pjit[
  jaxpr={ lambda ; b:key<fry>[] c:i32[] d:i32[]. let
      e:f32[] = convert_element_type[new_dtype=float32 weak_type=False] c
      f:f32[] = convert_element_type[new_dtype=float32 weak_type=False] d
      g:f32[] = div e 1.4142135381698608
      h:f32[] = erf g
      i:f32[] = div f 1.4142135381698608
      j:f32[] = erf i
      k:f32[376,256] = pjit[
        jaxpr={ lambda ; l:key<fry>[] m:f32[] n:f32[]. let
            o:f32[1,1] = broadcast_in_dim[broadcast_dimensions=() shape=(1, 1)] m
            p:f32[1,1] = broadcast_in_dim[broadcast_dimensions=() shape=(1, 1)] n
            q:u32[376,256] = random_bits[bit_width=32 shape=(376, 256)] l
            r:u32[376,256] = shift_right_logical q 9
            s:u32[376,256] = or r 1065353216
            t:f32[376,256] = bitcast_convert_type[new_dtype=float32] s
            u:f32[376,256] = sub t 1.0
            v:f32[1,1] = sub p o
            w:f32[376,256] = mul u v
            x:f32[376,256] = add w o
            y:f32[376,256] = max o x
          in (y,) }
        name=_uniform
      ] b h j
      z:f32[376,256] = erf_inv k
      ba:f32[376,256] = mul 1.4142135381698608 z
      bb:f32[] = stop_gradient e
      bc:f32[] = nextafter bb inf
      bd:f32[] = stop_gradient f
      be:f32[] = nextafter bd -inf
      bf:f32[376,256] = pjit[
        jaxpr={ lambda ; bg:f32[376,256] bh:f32[] bi:f32[]. let
            bj:f32[376,256] = max bh bg
            bk:f32[376,256] = min bi bj
          in (bk,) }
        name=clip
      ] ba bc be
    in (bf,) }
  name=_truncated_normal
] bl bm bn
    from line new.py:11 (my_func)

(Additional originating lines are not shown.)
See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.TracerArrayConversionError

The stack trace below excludes JAX-internal frames.
The preceding is the original exception that occurred, unmodified.

--------------------

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new.py", line 17, in <module>
    out = pmap(lambda _: my_func())(jnp.arange(2))
  File "new.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    out = pmap(lambda _: my_func())(jnp.arange(2))
  File "new.py", line 12, in my_func
    model.learn(total_timesteps=7e5, progress_bar=True)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sbx/sac/sac.py", line 173, in learn
    return super().learn(
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/off_policy_algorithm.py", line 328, in learn
    rollout = self.collect_rollouts(
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/off_policy_algorithm.py", line 557, in collect_rollouts
    actions, buffer_actions = self._sample_action(learning_starts, action_noise, env.num_envs)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/off_policy_algorithm.py", line 390, in _sample_action
    unscaled_action, _ = self.predict(self._last_obs, deterministic=False)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stable_baselines3/common/base_class.py", line 553, in predict
    return self.policy.predict(observation, state, episode_start, deterministic)
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sbx/common/policies.py", line 58, in predict
    actions = np.array(actions).reshape((-1, *self.action_space.shape))
jax.errors.TracerArrayConversionError: The numpy.ndarray conversion method __array__() was called on traced array with shape float32[1,17].
The error occurred while tracing the function <lambda> at new.py:17 for pmap. This value became a tracer due to JAX operations on these lines:

  operation a:i32[] = convert_element_type[new_dtype=int32 weak_type=False] b
    from line new.py:11 (my_func)

  operation a:u32[] = convert_element_type[new_dtype=uint32 weak_type=False] b
    from line new.py:11 (my_func)

  operation a:f32[] = convert_element_type[new_dtype=float32 weak_type=False] b
    from line new.py:11 (my_func)

  operation a:f32[] = convert_element_type[new_dtype=float32 weak_type=False] b
    from line new.py:11 (my_func)

  operation a:f32[376,256] = pjit[
  jaxpr={ lambda ; b:key<fry>[] c:i32[] d:i32[]. let
      e:f32[] = convert_element_type[new_dtype=float32 weak_type=False] c
      f:f32[] = convert_element_type[new_dtype=float32 weak_type=False] d
      g:f32[] = div e 1.4142135381698608
      h:f32[] = erf g
      i:f32[] = div f 1.4142135381698608
      j:f32[] = erf i
      k:f32[376,256] = pjit[
        jaxpr={ lambda ; l:key<fry>[] m:f32[] n:f32[]. let
            o:f32[1,1] = broadcast_in_dim[broadcast_dimensions=() shape=(1, 1)] m
            p:f32[1,1] = broadcast_in_dim[broadcast_dimensions=() shape=(1, 1)] n
            q:u32[376,256] = random_bits[bit_width=32 shape=(376, 256)] l
            r:u32[376,256] = shift_right_logical q 9
            s:u32[376,256] = or r 1065353216
            t:f32[376,256] = bitcast_convert_type[new_dtype=float32] s
            u:f32[376,256] = sub t 1.0
            v:f32[1,1] = sub p o
            w:f32[376,256] = mul u v
            x:f32[376,256] = add w o
            y:f32[376,256] = max o x
          in (y,) }
        name=_uniform
      ] b h j
      z:f32[376,256] = erf_inv k
      ba:f32[376,256] = mul 1.4142135381698608 z
      bb:f32[] = stop_gradient e
      bc:f32[] = nextafter bb inf
      bd:f32[] = stop_gradient f
      be:f32[] = nextafter bd -inf
      bf:f32[376,256] = pjit[
        jaxpr={ lambda ; bg:f32[376,256] bh:f32[] bi:f32[]. let
            bj:f32[376,256] = max bh bg
            bk:f32[376,256] = min bi bj
          in (bk,) }
        name=clip
      ] ba bc be
    in (bf,) }
  name=_truncated_normal
] bl bm bn
    from line new.py:11 (my_func)

(Additional originating lines are not shown.)
See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.TracerArrayConversionError
   0% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0/700,000  [ 0:00:00 < -:--:-- , ? it/s ]Exception ignored in: <function tqdm.__del__ at 0x7fa875eb8af0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1149, in __del__
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tqdm/rich.py", line 120, in close
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rich/progress.py", line 1177, in __exit__
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rich/progress.py", line 1163, in stop
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rich/live.py", line 155, in stop
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rich/console.py", line 1137, in line
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rich/console.py", line 1674, in print
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rich/console.py", line 1535, in _collect_renderables
  File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rich/protocol.py", line 28, in rich_cast
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
```

Basically I am trying to replace the parallelization performed by `joblib` with `JAX`. Here's my original program that I am changing -

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import gym
import os
from sbx import SAC
import multiprocessing

def my_func():

    env = gym.make("Humanoid-v4")

    model = SAC("MlpPolicy", env,verbose=0)
    model.learn(total_timesteps=7e5, progress_bar=True)


Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(my_func)() for i in range(2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 File "/home/thoma/anaconda3/envs/tbd/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sbx/common/policies.py", line 58, in predict
    actions = np.array(actions).reshape((-1, *self.action_space.shape))
```

The `sbx` package is calling `np.array` on the inputs – this tells me that `sbx` is built on NumPy, not on JAX. JAX transformations like `pmap` are not compatible with NumPy functions, they require functions written with JAX operations. Unless `sbx` is substantially re-designed, you won't be able to use it with `pmap`, `vmap`, `jit`, `grad`, or other JAX transformations.

Comment: My bad. I wasn't aware that `pmap` isn't compatible with `Numpy`. Thank you for the information.